# VBA programming-Access frontend

Tags: vba, ms-access, frontend

I am trying to fill out a form in which I have three dropdown menus (Here are their names: equipment type, Fouling type, Fouling Amount) and I have to choose a value from each and enter them to a list box (named :lstFouling) and create one row. Then I can add more rows by clicking on the add button and repeat the above process. Here is the problem: After entering several (2-3) rows, when I want to enter a new row, the previous rows are already deleted from the listbox. It seems the listbox does not hold the values although it has enough space in it. Any ideas how I can solve it? Here is the VBA code:

```
Private Sub lstFoulingPresence_GotFocus()

    Dim foulingRecord As Variant
    Dim entry As String
    
    foulingRecord = Array(6)
    lstFoulingPresence.RowSource = ""            ''Refresh the list box
    
    If intFoulingRecordCount > 0 Then
        
        For Each foulingRecord In varFoulingRecords
            If IsArray(foulingRecord) Then
                ''use the combo boxes along with row id's to get the name of each lookup value
                ''@TODO might need to write a script for getting the row number from the combo box where id is x
                Dim equipType As String
                Dim foulingType As String
                Dim foulingAmnt As String
                
                equipType = getFoulingPresenceEquipmentType(foulingRecord)
                foulingType = getFoulingPresenceFoulingType(foulingRecord)
                foulingAmnt = getFoulingPresenceFoulingAmount(foulingRecord)
                
                lstFoulingPresence.AddItem (CStr(foulingRecord(0)) + ";" + equipType + ";" + CStr(foulingRecord(1)) + ";" + foulingType + ";" + CStr(foulingRecord(2)) + ";" + foulingAmnt)
            End If
            
            ''txtFoulingPresenceCurrent.Value = txtFoulingPresenceCurrent.Value + " " + entry(0) + " " + entry(1) + " " + entry(2)
        Next foulingRecord
    End If
End Sub
```

I don't have an idea how I can fix it. Thanks in advance

Comment: Is there a reason why you are not storing the data in a table, but just putting it into the listbox?

Comment: Each time the procedure runs, `RowSource = ""` discards anything you added to the rowsource previously.  Does that explain the behavior you're seeing?

Comment: @HansUp Thanks, I commented out this line, still the same though

Comment: @SpencerBarnes No honestly. I can change it to table, do you think it is a problem with listbox?

Comment: What does getFoulingPresenceEquipmentType() function do? Have you step debugged? Not clear to me what purpose this listbox serves. Are you not saving combobox selections to a table?

Comment: I'm not honestly experienced enough to exactly say what storing data to a listbox can or can't do, but I know storing data to a table doesn't randomly drop information in the way you are describing. You then set the listbox rowsource to display data from the table, and update the listbox everytime you add data to the table.